# Search Service is not found in TFS WSS3.0 SP2 version

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, wss, sharepoint-search, sharepointadmin

I am trying to configure search service on WSS 3.0 which is installed with TFS 2010. I don't see the search service in "Servers in Farm". Without that I cannot do anything.

[image]

I tried to start service in "Services", got an error.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint version that comes with TFS is SharePoint Foundation. SharePoint Foundation does not include the Search Service. You will need Sharepoint Standard or Enterprise.